# how to return a string from a for loop instead of printing out one by one

Tags: python, for-loop, return

Im trying to make my for loop return a string of the whole word with a dash or each letter depending on guess_letters instead of print out each letter one by one for my hangman game.

Ive tried to print letter as a string, return letter then set a variable  to that function then print the variable.

```
import random

words = ['apple','python','parent']
def randomword(words):
  return random.choice(words)
chosenword = randomword(words)
tries = 10


guess_letters = []
def dashshow(guess_letters):
  for letter in chosenword:
    if letter in guess_letters:
      return str(letter)
      string_letter = dashshow(guess_letters)
      print(string_Letter)
    else: 
      return '-'
      dash_letter = dashshow(guess_letters)
      print(dash_letter)


def playgame(tries):
  while  tries != 0 and "_" in chosenword:
    print(f"You have {tries} tries left")
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter of the word")).lower()
    guess_letters.append(guess)
    if guess in chosenword:
      print("You got a letter correct!")
      turns -= 1
    else: 
      print("That letter is not in the word")
      turns -= 1


playgame(tries)
```

I thought it would print out the string with dashes or letters depending on the guessed_letters list but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: What is expected output? Add in your question.

Comment: `dashshow()` was not called anywhere. There many mistakes in that function. Explain why you created that and what want to return for those two function. In short explain your game logic clearly.

Comment: Just to note... `return` immediately stops a functions control flow and returns the given result. No other code is ran in that function after a `return` statement is ran.

Answer (score 0):

here is way you can. just modify as you need.Also, You can compare your code with this one. to find mistake.

```
import random

words = ['apple','python','parent']
def randomword(words):
    return random.choice(words)
chosenword = randomword(words)
print (chosenword) #this is random word you can delete this line.
tries = 10

guess_letters = []

def dashshow(guess_letter):
    guess_letters.append(guess_letter)
    print(guess_letters) # just to debug you can remove.
    if len(guess_letters) == len(chosenword):
        print("You Won Dear!")
        exit()

def playgame(tries):
  while tries != 0 :
    print(f"You have {tries} tries left")
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter of the word:> ")).lower()
    if any(guess in s for s in chosenword):
      print("You got a letter correct!")
      dashshow(guess)
      tries -= 1
    else:
      print("That letter is not in the word")
      tries -= 1


playgame(tries)
```